# WPF DataGrid Cell Horizontal Alignment Glitch

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an intermittent problem when center aligning text in WPF data grid text columns.

[image: Misaligned DataGrid Cell]

Notice the left alignment on the first cell. The problem corrects itself after waiting a few seconds, but what could cause this? I've seen this on several grids now, but cannot purposefully reproduce the issue in a fresh project. The grids are usually several layers deep in dockpanels, grids, and groupboxes. Here is the XAML used to style the pictured grid:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="GridRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14.667" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="OrderGridRowStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource GridRowStyle}"
                    TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static desktopViewModels:DisplayableOrderState.Uncommitted}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

Here is the grid definition:

```
 <DataGrid
                            x:Name="Orders"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            CanUserAddRows="False"
                            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                            CanUserSortColumns="False"
                            CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedOrderViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding OrderViewModels}"
                            RowStyle="{StaticResource OrderGridRowStyle}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrderViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Order Name"  Width="*"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CreatedDate}" Header="Created Date" Width ="*"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

I have tried explicitly specifying column widths instead of using * widths, but the problem persists. I've tried other methods of centering the grid cells, such as the following, also with no effect.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```